# Creating polygons from an RGB image in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygonize

I scoured the QGIS documentation and couldn't find anything.

What I am trying to achieve is a polygon covering a certain area, in my case, it's a glacier. The imagery of the glacier comes in the form of an RBG orthophoto from a WMTS server.
I could manually draw the polygon by clicking along the edges. This doesn't seem like a reasonable way to do this. There must be a way to create a polygon over areas with a distinctive RGB-value.

Comment: Are you asking how to do supervised image classification?

Comment: @Erik Yeah. I would like a polygon over all snow covered areas.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: What is the basis for your digitalisation - a RGB orthophoto?

Comment: @til_b Yes. Its an RBG orthophoto form a WMTS server.

Comment: I wasn't using fancy words to sound clever, but to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Erik I realized. Thank you. I am currently looking into the semi-automatic classification plug-in. Thats what i could find. Still trying to figure it out though. As til_b pointed out, it should also work with just RBG photos, right?

Comment: Try [i.segment](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/i.segment.html) and convert the output to vectors

Answer (score 3):

If the desired region really has a distinct RGB value, use the raster calculator to create a binary layer that is all ones for the desired region, zeros everywhere else. Then use the polygonize processing tool to convert to a vector layer. You can generalize this for the case where there's a range of RGB values, though the expression becomes a little harder to write.